# orange Logistic regression formula in OLTP

Tags: logistic-regression, orange

Once the log regression fn is known, how does one actually implement this in an online system for a new respondent, saying asking for a loan? Are we to call Python and Orange and pass a dataset with one record to the apis, or are we to take the function and embed it in Java, say? That is not clear to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can either call Python and Orange or take the learned LR model parameters (coefficients) and implement the LR classifier in Java.

So the answer is: yes.

Comment: OK, thx. That is hard to find, in R I found it immediately and could implement it.I will look again. I seemed to have missed where you could find that in ORANGE itself.